# Words describing college gates

Tags: word-choice

Are there any particular words to describe gates like theses ones?[image]

[image]

Comment: Lots of them: *iron, imposing, ornate*.

Comment: And can I use all three in one sentence? Or it will be too much?

Comment: Certainly you *can* use three of them, but two might be stylistically better. Either *ornate iron gates* or *imposing iron gates* should get the idea across. I don't know if there's a single word for gates like this.

Comment: If you're referring to the specific ironwork, they're called overthrows. If you're looking for descriptors, though, you have plenty to choose from @PeterShor's list.

Comment: I would say "wrought-iron gates". I think "wrought" adds something non-trivial here.

Comment: @PeterShor If you think they are imposing I suggest you look not at Clare College, Cambridge, see Trinity.

Comment: perhaps *rococo*?

Comment: @badroit: It does indeed. See my comment to Susan's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, gates are gates. There are garden gates, driveway gates, entry gates... the type of gate shown is a wrought iron entry gate, an elaborate, ornate one. But it's still a gate.

Comment: I would *guess* the specific term OP is looking for is ***wrought iron gates***. In which case it might be a good idea to point out, [as Steven Pinker likes to](http://www.mattababy.org/~belmonte/Publications/Reviews/99_pinker.html) that ***wrought** is actually is a conjugation of an archaic form of the verb **to work***. Which very few people know, despite the fact that practically everyone knows perfectly well what *wrought iron* is. Try it by asking a few friends (excluding any who've actually heard of Pinker! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - a good friend of mine is a blacksmith. It would not occur to me that people would not know what wrought iron meant.

Comment: I myself didn't know the *etymology* until 15 years ago when in a rare display of extravagance I pre-ordered a hardback copy of Pinkers *Words and Rules* (having just read *The Language Instinct* and decided to worship him! :). Coincidentally I met a guy about then who claimed to be the only working blacksmith in the county (in circumstances where he asked me not to repeat that information, as he didn't want to be identifiable). I recall with certainty that *he* didn't know it either, because that was what prompted me to bore everyone else I knew, by asking them if *they* knew it! Few did.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - then how would people understand the phrase, *What hast thou wrought?*

Comment: @Susan: some people think that *"wrought"* is an archaic past tense of *"wreak"*. With *"seek"* and *"sought"*, this isn't that implausible.

Comment: @Peter: I can't actually remember what if anything I thought about the etymology before reading it in Pinker, but I might well have supposed it was something to do with *write*, given that *scroll work* seems to be in the same general area.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I remember being quite surprised when I learned that it was the past tense of *work* (I think I thought it was *wreak* before). I also remember being unable to convince somebody it wasn't the past tense of *wreak*.

Comment: @Peter: I also can't remember (and can't be bothered to search for) Pinker's exact words in the book where I read it, but I'm pretty sure he mentioned that "not many people know that". Anyway, logic tells me he wouldn't have put it in the book at all if it was well-known to everyone. *And* logic tells me that given his profession, he ought to have a better idea than most as to what the average speaker does or doesn't know about such things.

Comment: ...belay that - I *can* be bothered, since one of the top google hits for *wrought pinker* is [this one](http://menachemkuchar.com/Writings/137.htm) by someone else who was clearly fascinated by it, and was kind enough to cite the entire context. Apparently you're in good company with ***wreak***, @Peter. The other hot contender is ***wring*** (I hope I *didn't* think it was ***write***, since it looks like I'd have been on my own with that one).